# How to configure "places" in MATE menu-bar

Tags: ubuntu

I'm testing Ubuntu MATE 16.04 alpha2

Where does one configure "places" in the MATE menu-bar?

using dconf-editor and do settings in org.mate.mate-menu.plugins.places does not have any effect.
removing .config and .cache and logout does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

MATE uses Caja for the bookmarks and the file browser window. The Places menu displays bookmarked places. To edit the bookmarks select 'Bookmarks->Edit Bookmarks' in a file browser window.  Then just remove the invalid bookmarks.